# Weblogic Scripting Tool common modules

Tags: weblogic11g, wlst

when using WLST, I encounter several problems.
We only use Solaris or Linux for our servers, so please remeber this when answering.

1: where should I place common modules for WLST that won't have anything to do with internal WLST-functions(option parsing, logging, output, ...)
1.1: I have written a few of my own, to account for the lack of existing within Jython 2.1 supplied by Oracle.

2: How can I include modules that use WLST internal functions so that they work, and don't lose their information(connect in a module doesn't stay connected when back in the main program).

Greetings

Comment: did you take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm#autoId34)? Specifically "WLST commands as a Jython module".

Comment: I have looked, I have tried, I have failed. I'll try again though. But this only covers Q2

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the 'new' module you wrote uses the existing WLST functions. All that needs to be done is to put these 'new' py files under $WL_HOME/common/wlst and they are imported during WLST start up. Let me know what error you are facing while doing this.

Comment: when using a WLST-function(connect for example) without import WLST in my new module, it gives a NameError. The module is correctly loaded though, so thanks for that in any case :-)

Comment: however, when importing wlstModule in my self-written module, when I do connect, it does not propagate it to the main stream

Comment: could you please paste the code? I can understand some part of what you are saying, but seeing the code will be better for a completely understanding. What I am looking for is : your module, how you invoked it.

Comment: You can also [invoke Jython directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931155/invoking-jython-without-weblogics-wlst) and use [WLST as a module](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm#autoId33) only when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1 I am able to include library .py files in the same directory as the target script by adding the current path to sys.path. For instance, if I have a file functions.py, I would use this code:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(lambda:(True)))))
import functions
```

I'm not sure if adding to sys.path is the Pythonic way of doing things, but it gets the job done and WLST is pretty ["Wild West"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding) as well.

If you're stuck using an older version of Weblogic like 10.x (and possibly 11g?), that embeds Python 2.1, you'll find that it doesn't have many now-standard libraries including the inspect library. You'll have to use `sys.argv[0]` instead of `os.path.abspath(inspect.getsourcefile(lambda:(True)))`.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, I follow Ed Griebel's approach to append to the sys.path.  To support older versions, I leverage the sys.argv[0] variable.

For #2, if you're doing an "import wlstModule" in your module, then in the main script I found you need to bypass the internal WLST functions provided and instead use the ones from wlstModule.  Simply add the same "import wlstModule" within your main script then change all of your calls to use the imported wlstModule.  For example, in your main script use calls like "wlstModule.cd()", "wlstModule.cmo()", and "wlstModule.set()", not "cd()", "cmo()", and "set()".