# Invoking Jython without Weblogic's WLST

Tags: weblogic, jython, wlst

I'm using an AIX machine which has Weblogic 9.21 installed and it also has jython as part of its installation (WLST).

Is there a way to run jython code without having to initialize the WLST first?

I have the following jars too if they bring in any ideas:

```
['.', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/lib/jython.jar', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/lib/config.jar', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/lib/config.jar', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/wlst/modules/jython-modules.jar/Lib', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/wlst', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/wlst/lib', '/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/wlst/modules']
```

Right now I'm invoking the jython code using:

```
java -cp /opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST file.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste below code in a shell script say `jythonExec.sh` and use it

Example Usage : `/bin/bash jythonExec.sh file.py`

```
#!/bin/bash 
jythonJarLoc=/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/common/lib/jython.jar
javaLoc=/usr/bin/java
pythonCacheDir=/tmp/pythonCacheDir
if [ ! -f ${jythonJarLoc} ]; then
    jythonJarLoc=/opt/weblogic921/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar
fi
${javaLoc} -cp ${jythonJarLoc} -Dpython.cachedir=${pythonCacheDir} org.python.util.jython $@
```